# Remove NaN from lists in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, python-applymap

I have a dataframe whose values are lists which contains 'nan'. Is there an easy and pythonic way to remove those 'nan' values from lists within the dataframe? I have defined a function which returns a list without 'nan', but how can I apply it to dataframe inplace?

```
def remove_nan(input_list):
    temp_list = [x for x in input_list if x!='nan']
    return temp_list

test = ['nan', 'nan', 'SHM System', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']

remove_nan(test)
['SHM System']
```

This function works on individual list and returns clean list as shown in the output above. How can I apply this function, or if there is a better way, to remove all 'nan' values from lists within a [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aw5r.jpg)? I have tried applymap and apply but didn`t work.

```
df_combined.applymap(remove_nan)
```

Comment: Show your bit of code that didn't work too... [ask] [mre]

Comment: This is what I did:

df_combined.applymap(remove_nan)
It didn`t change the dataframe.

Comment: `df.applymap(lambda x: [*filter(pd.notna, x)])`

Comment: Did you try `df_combined = df_combined.applymap(remove_nan)` ? The applymap method doesn't modify the original DataFrame unless you set it equal to what it's returning

Comment: @DerekO Yeah, I can see the copy of this data frame, it is same. Hasn`t changed.

Comment: I tried with an example DataFrame using your variable `test`, and it seems to work: `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[test]*3,'b':[test]*3})` to create a DataFrame with lists containing 'nan' as you described, then `df = df.applymap(remove_nan)` modifies df so that none of the entries contain the string `nan`

Comment: Yeah, this example also works for me, but same code doesnt work on the dataframe I`m trying to clean. However, solution from @piRSquared did work. 
Thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line of code worked for me. Thanks to @piRSquared.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: [*filter(pd.notna, x)])
```